# Is there a more idiomatic way to initialize an array with random numbers than a for loop?

Tags: rust

Is there an idiomatic way of initialising arrays in Rust. I'm creating an array of random numbers and was wondering if there is a more idiomatic way then just doing a for loop. My current code works fine, but seems more like C than proper Rust:

```
let mut my_array: [u64; 8] = [0; 8];
for i in 0..my_array.len() {
    my_array[i] = some_function();
}
```

Comment: You may find this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282970/does-rust-have-an-equivalent-to-pythons-list-comprehension-syntax) helpful. Basically you can use a list comprehension to initialize your array.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Various sized arrays](https://docs.rs/rand/0.7.3/rand/distributions/struct.Standard.html) can be directly randomly generated:

```
use rand; // 0.7.3

fn main() {
    let my_array: [u64; 8] = rand::random();
    println!("{:?}", my_array);
}
```

Currently, this only works for arrays of size from 0 to 32 (inclusive). Beyond that, you will want to see related questions:

- [How can I initialize an array using a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36925673/155423)
- [What is the proper way to initialize a fixed length array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31360993/155423)

Answer (score 2):

The other solution is nice and short, but does not apply to the case where you need to initialize an array of random numbers in a specific range. So, here's an answer that addresses that case.

```
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

fn main() {
    let a = [(); 8].map(|_| thread_rng().gen_range(0.0..1.0));
    println!("The array of random float numbers between 0.0 and 1.0 is: {:?}", a);
}
```

I would be happy to know if there's a better (shorter and more efficient) solution than this one.

Comment: This solves the problem for `float` but the OP was asking about `u64`; looks like all you need to do is change `0.0..1.0` to `0..5555` or whatever your desired range is.